# Custom function to quit processing asp.net request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I´m come from old VB totaly new to C#. I want to build a helper function, that I can call in this way:

```
 void fError(400, "Parameter X is missing");
```

or

```
 void fError(500, "Unexpected Error occured");
```

This should be a "shortcut" for me: only one line to quit processing the page with my custom error messages and Standard http error codes.

This should be my "function":

```
    private void fError(int pErrorCode, string pErrorMessage)
    {
        var mCode;
        if (pErrorCode == 500)
        {
            mCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        if (pErrorCode == 400)
        {
            mCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(mCode)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(pErrorMessage),
            ReasonPhrase = "MyApplication Error"
        });
    }
```

Any idea how to get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're almost there. your code seems to suggest you're using ASP.NET Web API.
let me know if now.

you can simplify your code further by using.

```
  private void fError(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string pErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(statusCode)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(pErrorMessage),
            ReasonPhrase = "MyApplication Error"
        });
    }
```

OR, if you don't want to send HttpStatusCode types (why not?) and want to send integers

```
  private void fError(int statusCode, string pErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException((HttpStatusCode)statusCode)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(pErrorMessage),
            ReasonPhrase = "MyApplication Error"
        });
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! First solution works for me. And you´r right: it is within a Web Api application. Can you explain what are the differences between `HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)` and `HttpResponseException((HttpStatusCode)500)`? I would like to use the second Version, because not all possible statuscodes are in the predefined list.

Comment: first version is better in terms of readability & any testing, and it is less prone to errors. what status codes are you looking for which is not in the predefined list?

Comment: `first version is better in terms of readability & any testing` you´re right. but as Long as Microsoft does not provide all http status codes, i prefer the hand-made solution... e.g. I miss 424 (Failed Dependency) or 422 (Unprocessable Entity) for my Web Api.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with the second solution:

```
    public static void fError(string pErrorMessage, int pStatusCode)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)pStatusCode,
            Content = new StringContent(pErrorMessage),
            ReasonPhrase = "MyApplication Error"
        });
    }
```